# keyPress() not capturing key events AWT

Tags: java, awt

To get acquainted with the class robot decided to make a program that would control the character from the game Minecraft, but unfortunately this code does not work in the game. The letter is printed in a notebook, but can not get the character out of the game to walk.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
            robot.delay(1000);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as it's just pressing and releasing the key like any user. Note that you should focus on game *while* robot is pressing the key otherwise it'll be pressing key for currently focused application.

Do following,

- Add initial delay to Robot, `robot.delay(5000);`
- Run the robot program
- Switch to the game or focus on the app for which you want to press this key
- Wait for Robot to act!

Robot will blindly press and release key irrespective of the app.